# why Multipart/form-data removing Nill in response Mule Dataweave

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

Please find my request having tag `<Date xsi:nil="true"/>` when it crosses the `Multipart/form-data` dataweave it is removing the `xsi:nil="true` part which is not expected in my scenario. I wanted that to be out as the same.

Also it is removing the namespace which is not the expected case. If i trying declaring `ns xsi http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance` in the first dataweave. In the response  root element it is prefixing `xsi:Locations`. 
Im struggling with this.

Wanted the response as mentioned below, whatever the input is same should come out without altering.

Using `writeNilOnNull=true` is putting nill on all the fields which i dont want either, wanted only for date.

Could anyone help on this. Thank you.

Input:

```
<Locations xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Location>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <CarId>78</CarId>
    <Packages>1</Packages>
    <Date xsi:nil="true"/>
   </Location>
</Locations>
```

Expected Response:

```
 <Locations xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Location>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <CarId>78</CarId>
     <Packages/>
    <Date xsi:nil="true"/>
   </Location>
</Locations>
```

Flow:

```
        <flow name="question" doc:id="8c836a85-9d0a-47a8-8e5a-f670b16f91eb" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="52ffdb08-9587-4cb2-8232-9467e85ea0dc" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/question"/>
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="da995adf-196b-4c7b-a265-874f059ed1bb" >
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/xml 
---
payload]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="75e5d876-855e-4d38-8468-3484c859f36e" >
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output multipart/form-data 
---
{
  "parts": {
    "file": {
      "headers": {
        "Content-Disposition": {
          "name": "file",
          "filename": "",
          "subtype": "form-data"
        },
        "Content-Type": "application/xml"
      },
      "content": payload
    }
  }
}]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Comment: The problem is not the form-data transformation, it is in the first transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Add **writeNilOnNull=true** on your transformation. Like this

```
%dw 2.0
var x=read('<Locations xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Location>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <CarId>78</CarId>
    <Packages>1</Packages>
    <Date xsi:nil="true"/>
   </Location>
</Locations>','application/xml')
output application/xml writeNilOnNull=true
---
x
```

[image]